# Git diffing crashes on Windows when submodules exist

Tags: windows, git, shell, diff, msysgit

Using [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) on windows, whenever I do `git diff` on a repository that has a submodule or several, the command prompt (and also PowerShell) crash.

Is this a known but and is there a fix/workaround? Can I exclude submodules from diff?

Also:

```
PS Z:\www\gittest> git --version
git version 1.7.6.msysgit.0
```

**EDIT:** This has also [been reported](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/msysgit/LLtGakqxMzs/discussion) on the msysgit google group.

Comment: What do you mean by a crash? What exactly happens?

Comment: Both command prompt and PowerShell just crash. Literally crash. What else is there to say? :P Without submodules, I get the output. With submodules in the repository, the cli hangs for a second and crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce such issues with diff and submodules, but if you don't care about submodules diff, you can do:

```
git diff --ignore-submodules
```

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this by installing [Microsoft kb2458000 (The conhost.exe process crashes when an application exits on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2458000).