# Git PowerShell session in Github Windows kept crashing

Tags: powershell, github, github-for-windows

GitHub for Windows provides the Git Shell via PowerShell, which is great under Windows. Most of my machines works well with it, but on one laptop (Thinkpad X1 carbon) the Git Shell (PowerShell) kept crashing after input a few cmdlets, even like ls, under a git repository, but it didn't crash out of a git repo.

What logs contain the error information, or anyone has clue about the crash?

GitHub for Windows latest (2.3.1) ran on Windows 8/8.1 64bit. However, my another box with the same OS and git / GitHub client works fine.

Event log reported an Application Error (quite general...):

Faulting application name: conhost.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17238, time stamp: 0x53d0cdd9
Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215f944
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x000000000000193f
Faulting process id: 0x2650
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfc50e4c68f5f7
Faulting application path: C:\windows\system32\conhost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
Report Id: 9ab0281b-3101-11e4-827c-b8763fa7c332
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Would this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9246078/6309) help? What OS and version of git are you using?

Comment: Seems not the same issue. My crash happened no matter what command or comdlet used, even not git command. updated the OS/GitHub client info as well.

Comment: Any error message? What the Windows Event log contains? What Windows it is? 7? 8? 32bits, 64bits? What msysgit is it?

Comment: Mysysgit (git bash) worked well, but Git Powershell session crashed.

Comment: Are all Windows update installed? (like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836988, which includes resolving an issue that could cause Console Host (ConHost.exe) to crash when you run an application that writes to an inactive screen buffer.

Comment: Current OS is Windows 8.1 so support.microsoft.com/kb/2836988 doesn't apply. Meanwhile checked Windows Update all installed.

Comment: Ok. Is there an anti-virus that might interfere with Powershell? (ie, does the issue persists with that anti-virus turned off?)

Comment: I only had Microsoft Security Essentials on the machine and even uninstalling it gives no luck. :(

Comment: Might it be something related to the version(s) of the .Net framework installed on your machines? Have you .Net 3.5 on both?

Comment: .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.5 are both installed on both machines.